# Can i use razor base web application in asp.net core 2.0.0 for authorization?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0

In Microsoft document, it is just with MVC,
I'm very beginner in .net-core-2.0.0 and I want to know  can I start authorization 
with razor base template?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find some answers:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/15/get-started-with-asp-net-core-authorization-part-1-of-2/

Inshort you can use attrinbutes like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @”DomainUsers”)]
```